# Type 1 and Type 2 error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

What is/are the statistical term/s for the region/s where the type1 and type2 errors occur/intersect (in the diagram Red + Blue regions or in part)?[image: Error rate]
THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you mean _critical value_?

Comment: Do you mean to refer to the sum of the blue and red areas, or the point where they intersect?

Comment: @BruceET, maybe. If I use "critical value" does it represents the entire colored area (a combination of Type 1 and Type 2 errors). If I write this on a paper, do statisticians understand what I meant? Thanks.

Comment: @JoelW. For the sum and, if any, for the parts. Is there a term for the intersection too? Thanks!

Comment: There is 'rejection region', 'acceptance region' or 'non-rejection region' and 'critical value' separating them.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks!  alpha=p(type 1 error), beta = p(type 2 error), and total error =alpha*p(H0) + beta*p(H1) where beta is a function of alpha. One metric of the effectiveness of a hypothesis test is the integral of the intersection of the two distributions. Basically, the smaller the integral of the intersection, the better the theory, and the data are at separating the null from the alternative, so the more likely the test is to lead the tester to make a correct conclusion. In this situation. Any terms for this matric?